# Stripping script tags and css links from ajax response removing other data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to remove the `<script>` tags from the ajax response. I'm returning a json encoded array from the server. But it contains some `<script>` tags also (coming from my application. Can't remove it from server side).

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {},
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("text : "+$(data).find("script,style").remove().end().text());
         }
});
```

I tried with the above code. It is removing the  tags. But a part of the last item from my json encoded array is also getting removed.

The string from test.php looks like

```
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
["Ball > Backs > Flags","Baseball > Backs > 3X5 Flags","Baseball > Backs > Action"] // like this it contains about 50 items.
```

`$(data).find("script,style").remove().end().text()` is returning the json string as  `["Ball > Backs > Flags","Baseball > Backs > 3X5 Flags","Baseball > Backs >` .

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help me to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

You make a mistake in ajax function. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

Here see **demo**:

https://jsbin.com/sazifefute/edit?html,output

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
       var rex = /<([^ >]+)[^>]*>.*?<\/\1>|<[^\/]+\/>/ig;
       data = data.replace(rex , "");
       console.log("text : "+ data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tried with this. The json string is coming correct now. But the css `link` is not getting removed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use replace() function to remove 'script' from the success resposne.

data.replace('script', "");